# Decoupling caller from callee in C# using delegate/BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, begininvoke

In C# I have a hierarchy of classes that perform actions that could potentially take a long time. For this reason, I implemented a decoupling/callback mechanism so the caller is not blocked, but is informed of an action's completion through a callback interface. This looks something like this:

```
protected delegate void ActionDelegate();
public void doAction()
{
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoActionASync());
}
private void DoActionASync()
{
  DoActionImpl(); 
  Caller->ActionDone(); // Caller is registered separately, and implements an interface (ICallback) that includes this function
}
protected abstract void DoActionImpl(); // Derived classes implement this
```

This is quite a lot of code that is repeated with minor differences (in signature) for each method. My question is whether this is the right way to approach this, or does .NET/C# offer any constructs that would make this easier/less verbose?

Comment: does caller and callee are in different threads?

Comment: There's something to be said for not writing this code.  You are missing the required EndInvoke() call.  Helper classes to get this right are Task in .NET 4 and BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @Hans: That's good info. The Task class is indeed a better way to start a new thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is good documentation on [asynchronous programming patterns on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx). If you are using .NET 4, you should look into the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) (TPL).

Asynchronous programming using delegates is covered [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx) (there is also an extra  [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h80ttd5f.aspx)). You could do much worse that follow MSDN's practices and suggestions.

Comment: I thought Microsoft's offical stance was that TPL wasn't ready for production code?

Comment: @Ramhound: If it's not ready for production I don't think MS (or anyone else) would promote it as one of the major features in their new framework release. You are probably mistaken.